# ExtJS 3.4 :: Grid with all NumberField editors fails to update store

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a grid and so long as at least one of the columns has an Ext.form.TextField editor, then edits to the grid result in the store's beforewrite, beforesave events firing as expected.

However, if *all* columns Ext.form.NumberField editors, then edits to them do *not* fire these store events.

I see no errors.

Does anyone know what I might look at to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: You might look at showing the code that is causing the problem

Comment: Can you post some sample code?